# Is this allowed: memcpy(dest, src, 0)

Tags: c++, c

Is there a problem in passing `0` to `memcpy()`:

```
 memcpy(dest, src, 0)
```

Note that in my code I am using a variable instead of `0`, which can sometimes evaluate to `0`.

Comment: yes of course you can

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As one might expect from a sane interface, zero is a valid size, and results in nothing happening. It's specifically allowed by the specification of the various string handling functions (including `memcpy`) in C99 7.21.1/2:

> Where an argument declared as `size_t n` specifies the length of the array for a function, **`n` can have the value zero** on a call to that function. [...] On such a call, a function that locates a character finds no occurrence, a function that compares two  character sequences returns zero, and **a function that copies characters copies zero characters**.

Comment: **But** `dest` and `src` must be valid pointers, even when `n == 0`, so they must not be null.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's totally Ok. The only restriction on memcpy is that memory areas must not overlap.

Comment: That's not true, there is also a restriction that `dest` and `src` are valid pointers, meaning they cannot be null. See 7.23.1 and 7.1.4

Comment: That's not the only restriction (both pointers must be valid, and `dest` must be at least as large as `n`, for example). But you're right that there's no restriction that `n` be non-zero.