# Is memcpy(dest, src, 0) defined in the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, standards, memcpy

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751797/can-i-call-memcpy-and-memmove-with-number-of-bytes-set-to-zero) and [many more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506782/is-this-allowed-memcpydest-src-0) are among the numerous questions on this site that ask if a call to `memcpy()` is valid with a length\size specified with a zero value.
When answering, everyone quotes the current **C** standard (in this case [C17 ISO/IEC9899:2017 page 283](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf#page=283) ),

> Where an argument declared as `size_t` `n` specifies the length of the array for a function, `n` can have
>   the value zero on a call to that function. Unless explicitly stated otherwise in the description of a
>   particular function in this subclause, pointer arguments on such a call shall still have valid values, as
>   described in 7.1.4. On such a call, a function that locates a character finds no occurrence, a function
>   that compares two character sequences returns zero, and a function that copies characters copies
>   zero characters.

However, this is from **C** standard, **not** quoted from the **C++** standard.

Where in the current **C++** standard (i.e. C++17 ISO/IEC 14882) is this same definition listed? **C** and **C++** have two different standards (and languages) and from my understanding, you cannot quote one and expect that same rule/behavior to be present in the other standard.

If this quotation from the **C** standard is valid in **C++** without explicitly stating it in the standard, can someone then provide a source that backs up this connection between **C** and **C++**?

Comment: memcpy's man page says that the function "Copies the values of `num` bytes from the location pointed to by source" ... and 0 is a perfectly valid value of `num`.  Is that sufficient?   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

Comment: @JeremyFriesner According to [International Organization for Standardization's (ISO) website on C++](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard), "*sites like cppreference.com and cplusplus.com [are not authoritative and are used for unofficial references].*"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++17 standards says this about [the C standard library](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/library.c):

> 1
>   The C++ standard library also makes available the facilities of the C standard library, suitably adjusted to ensure static type safety.
>
> 2
>   The descriptions of many library functions rely on the C standard library for the semantics of those functions. In some cases, the signatures specified in this International Standard may be different from the signatures in the C standard library, and additional overloads may be declared in this International Standard, but the behavior and the preconditions (including any preconditions implied by the use of an ISO C `restrict` qualifier) are the same unless otherwise stated.

As to your question,

> If this quotation from the C standard is valid in C++ without explicitly stating it in the standard

The answer is "yes".

Answer (score 1):

[[library.c]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/library.c#2), emphasis mine:

> The descriptions of many library functions rely on the C standard library for the semantics of those functions.
>   In some cases, the signatures specified in this document may be different from the signatures in the C standard library, and additional overloads may be declared in this document, but **the behavior and the preconditions** (including any preconditions implied by the use of an ISO C restrict qualifier) **are the same unless otherwise stated**.

[[cstring.syn]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/cstring.syn#1):

> The contents and meaning of the header `<cstring>` are the same as the C standard library header `<string.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

The C library is sort of baked into C++. As said in [intro.scope] from the C++17 standard (emphasis mine):

> 2. C++ is a general purpose programming language **based on the C programming language** as described in
>      ISO/IEC 9899:2011 Programming languages — C (**hereinafter referred to as the C standard**). **In addition to
>      the facilities provided by C**, C++ provides additional data types, classes, templates, exceptions, namespaces,
>      operator overloading, function name overloading, references, free store management operators, and additional
>      library facilities.

And again, in [intro.refs]:

> 2. The library described in Clause 7 of ISO/IEC 9899:2011 is hereinafter called the **C standard library**.1
>
> ---
>
> 1) With the qualifications noted in Clauses 21 through 33 and in C.5, **the C standard library is a subset of the C++ standard
>   library.**

So everything that is in the C standard library is in C++.